# How to use custom schema which is created by us in postgresql rds as target instead of public schema in aws glue job?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to move table from aws data catalog to the schema which i created in aurora postgresql instance. I tried this using glue job. I have created connection for postgres tried adding schema in the url. Test connection was successful. Used the same connection in the glue job. The job runs successfully but creates the table in public schema but, i need the table to be created in the schema created by me.

Comment: Set the `search_path` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my question. Posting the solution here if anyone needs in future. Inside the script generated by aws, We need to add Schemaname.tablename in the place of target table name (ex consider u have x_schema and T1 table then u need to give as x_schema.t1 to move table in x_schema)